# Polymer JS elements for Polymer Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, polymer

I try port polymer element, for using it with dart.
I use custom_element_apigen package.
When i run pub, i get Build error:

```
pub serve example/
Loading source assets... 
Loading polymer transformers... (1.6s) 
Serving wysiwyg_e example/ on http://localhost:8080
Build error:
Transforms {Dart2JS on wysiwyg_e|example/packages/test/src/runner/browser/static/host.dart} all emitted asset wysiwyg_e|example/packages/test/src/runner/browser/static/host.dart.js.
```

And some errors like:

```
[Error from WebComponents on wysiwyg_e|example/index.html]:
Could not load asset wysiwyg_e|lib/paper_tooltip.dart
[Error from WebComponents on wysiwyg_e|example/index.html]:
Could not load asset wysiwyg_e|lib/prism_import.dart
[Error from WebComponents on wysiwyg_e|example/index.html]:
Could not load asset wysiwyg_e|lib/behavior.dart
```

How i can port polymer js with custom_element_apigen? I must add all bower packages in gen.yaml? What does this error mean?

Comment: A bug report in the custom_element_apigen GitHub repo might help.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do it. Thank you.

Comment: I've used custom_element_apigen in my project.  You might take a look there as another example of its use: [polymer-app-layout](https://github.com/ilikerobots/polymer-app-layout)